# Datapicker check the age of users and sometimes saves a wrong value in DB

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Date-of-Birth-Age-validation-with-jQuery-DatePicker.aspx), but I have it slightly modified some fields for my needs, nothing special, just :

```
$('.txtDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'focus',
        showAnim: "fadeIn",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        autoSize: true,
        yearRange: '1900:+0',
        onSelect: function (dateString, txtDate) {
            ValidateDOB(dateString, txtDate.id);
        }
    });
```

these are html inputs (I have multiple of them):

```
 <label class="mr-3" for="c1_dob">Birthday <span>*</span></label>
 <input class="txtDate" type="text" id="c1_dob" autocomplete="off" name="c1_dob" onkeydown="return false;" required/>
```

the rpoblem is, that sometimes the date is saved to DB as 1970-01-01. At which input will that happen is also not clear. Pure random.
can some1 point me, why does it happen? If you need to see more code, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: why not debug that at your server end while taking value of inputs using post or get ?

Comment: there are a lot of different inputs within my form with different values. For DoB I have 3 to 4 inputs. c1_dob, c2_dob and so on. Everything will be correctly in db saved except sometimes(!) wrong date. Sometimes 1970 is by s1_dob saved, sometimes by c3_dob, sometimes 2 of 4 fields with wrong date, sometimes they ALL are correctly saved. I can't understand how to debug such a behaviour. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: See if correct values are getting pass to your backend page . Also , are you checking for null values before saving them in db and is your data submitted using ajax or form ?

Comment: I am using form with post method to the same php file. Users cannot submit form without choosing the DoB. So they have to choose date. But var_dump on form array after submit I  can see that all values are there. After form submitted I filter this array, then chunk it, adding some other values and send it to a backend class, in which the array will be correctly processed and everything will be saved to db. I am not loosing any value. One thing: I perform date converting: $dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_array['dob']));

Comment: did you check if `$dob` has right values after converting ?

Comment: ok, I think I found. Need to make urgent debug. It can be chunk problem. As soon as I get any new details I'll post it here.

Comment: now the dates before converting:  "05/03/1986", "01/03/1978", "16/03/1983", "01/03/2018". Now the dates AFTER convertion: "1986-05-03", "1978-01-03", "1970-01-01",  "2018-01-03".   ---- There 1970 is as third value (((

Comment: if I do NOT convert to date and change column type from DATE to VARCHAR, the dates are correctly saved, of course as a string. So that means that  ´date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_array[7]))´ does not work properly. Why the hell ist that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> So that means that ´date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_array[7]))´ does not work properly.

You use `strtotime()` with a date format like `dd/mm/yyyy`... But it expects `mm/dd/yyyy`. So the day and month are "reversed" in the parsing process.

See PHP documentation [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

---

Your PHP fix will be to reverse them:

```
<?php
$dateSplit = explode("/", $next_array[7]);  // "16/03/1983";
$datefixed = $dateSplit[1]."/".$dateSplit[0]."/".$dateSplit[2];
$iso_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datefixed));

echo $iso_date; // Outputs "1983-03-16"
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, will check later. But I already marked your answer, because it could be nothing else.